# Adding a class to a GameObject from a list of classes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've got a class containing a heap of different variables. I've then created a list of that class, each containing different values for each of those variables.

for each class in that list, I want to instantiate a GameObject Prefab I have, with the class from the list containing all the relevant values.

I'm wondering how (if possible), to add the class to the GameObject straight off the list and have it inherit the values without having to populate each variable individually.

e.g. something like...

```
for (int i=0; i < ClassList.Count; i++) {
    gameObject.AddComponent(ClassList[i]);
    Instantiate(gameObject, pos);
}
```

Rather than...

```
for (int i=0; i < ClassList.Count; i++) {
    gameObject.AddComponent(Class);
    gameObject.GetComponent<Class>().Var1 = ClassList[i].Var1;
    gameObject.GetComponent<Class>().Var2 = ClassList[i].Var2;
    etc...
    Instantiate(gameObject, pos);
}
```

I've tried to have the class as a component on the prefab first, but arrived at the same problem. I can't find any solution that allows you to populate all the variables of a class without going through them individually.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Would something speak against simply having a prefilled prefab and spawn instances as child of your root GameObject instance? And then e.g simply reference those in a component on the root object .. That would probably be the most straight forward solution I can think of rn ..

Comment: Other than that it is quite hard to tell where you are going as we don't know any further details about the content of `ClassList` and where it comes from ... and what exactly is your use case / intent with this at all